# Index and Concat / Concatenate from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, formula, array-formulas

I have a data sheet which i want to index pull into another sheet and also concanate or concat 2 or more columns with array formula.

sheet link here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUI-Gl7HDNGg5V2wM4ossUn46cp7VHRBZ_t4la2gDH0/edit?usp=sharing

data sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUI-Gl7HDNGg5V2wM4ossUn46cp7VHRBZ_t4la2gDH0/edit#gid=0

result required sample sheet  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUI-Gl7HDNGg5V2wM4ossUn46cp7VHRBZ_t4la2gDH0/edit#gid=1226812843
you can see in result sheet column B and F which are merged from "data sheet column b c d and h i simultaneously"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276). **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    DATA!A1:A, 
    trim( 
      DATA!B1:B & " " & 
      if( iserror(search(DATA!C1:C, DATA!B1:B)), DATA!C1:C, "" ) & " " & 
      if( iserror(search(DATA!D1:D, DATA!B1:B)), DATA!D1:D, "" ) 
    ), 
    DATA!E1:G, 
    trim(DATA!H1:H & if(len(DATA!I1:I), " / " & DATA!I1:I, "")), 
    DATA!J1:U 
  } 
)
```

The formula will only append the values in columns `C` and `D` to the value in column `B` when they do not not already appear in the value in column `B`.

Comment: Hi 
that works fine, almost all the options shared by you guys worked with **one issue in row 13** column B [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUI-Gl7HDNGg5V2wM4ossUn46cp7VHRBZ_t4la2gDH0/edit#gid=0)  i want to use the first word only, in fact this can occur in another columns too... in that scenario i want to pull only the first word. 

Also what if i want the initials only of column C cells.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: no brother there will be a issue with such method you can check row 12 and 13 now, i made some tweeks and it is showing result which i dont want....

cant we include **=LEFT(B13,FIND(" ",B13)-1)** something like this for every column

Comment: The first formula I gave you already matched the desired results you showed, and still show, at the 'Result Needed' tab. You should not modify your question to add new requirements after you have already received an answer. Please post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

the prior answer is ok but did you know...

[image]

so your issue can be solved as:

```
=BYROW(DATA!A2:INDEX(DATA!A:A, COUNTA(DATA!A:A)), 
 LAMBDA(a, {a, TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, OFFSET(a,,1,,3)), OFFSET(a,,4,,3), 
 TEXTJOIN(" / ", 1, OFFSET(a,,7,,2)), OFFSET(a,,9,,11)}))
```

[image]